# Use dropwizards annotation with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, codahale-metrics, spring-boot-actuator

Instead of measuring by inserting code into each method of interest I intended to use the provided `@Timed` annotation. But the metrics do not show any corresponding values:

[image: Metrics]

This is my code, the idea is having the execution times of the contained SQL being put into the metrics.

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public Metadata(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Timed(name = "myapp.get.foo")
    public boolean getFoo(final String foo ) {
        String foo = jdbcTemplate.query( ...
    }
}
```

The problem with `@Timed` not showing up is probably because [Spring Boot only supports Counter and Gauge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-recording-metrics).

But `@Gauge`, `@Metered` and `@Counted` don't work either.

What am I missing in order to make at least those metrics annotation work that are supported by Spring Boot ? (1.3.1 in my tests)

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to take a look at
http://www.ryantenney.com/metrics-spring/

This projects eases integration of dropwizard metrics into Spring Boot projects.
It will automatically create metrics and proxies beans to make the @Timed annotation work.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the annotations and simply implementing MetricSet on beans that I want to instrument. Especially with timers, using one is not that hard.

```
@Service
public class MyBean implements MetricSet {
    Timer putTimer = new Timer();

    public void someService() {
       try(Context context = putTimer.time()) {
          ....
       }
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Metric> getMetrics() {
        Map<String,Metric> metrics=new HashMap<>();
        metrics.put("mymetricname",putTimer);
        return metrics;
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public class MetricsContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    public MetricsContextListener(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        this.metricRegistry = metricRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        Map<String, MetricSet> beans = event.getApplicationContext().getBeansOfType(MetricSet.class);
        for(Map.Entry<String, MetricSet> e: beans.entrySet()) {
            log.info("registering " + e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue().getClass().getName());
            metricRegistry.register(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Also you'll probably want to create your own MetricRegistry. We had some issues with spring boot creating one but our spring tests failing because it was missing. If you create one yourself, that problem goes away. Simply add this to one of your `@Configuration` classes

```
@Bean
public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
    // explicitly register a metricRegistry so we can run our spring tests without relying on spring boot creating
    // one for us. Spring boot seems to do the right thing either way.
    // Used to register codahale metrics from MetricSet implementing beans.
    return new MetricRegistry();
}
```

With all this in place, Spring boot does the right thing and adds the metrics to /metrics.